# /System/Library/LaunchAgents is locked in El Capitan

Tags: launchd, macos

I'm trying to achieve this:
[Make my password protected SSH key expire or timeout after a while](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118223/make-my-password-protected-ssh-key-expire-or-timeout-after-a-while)

In Yosemite, this worked fantastic, in El Capitan, using sudo, the files in /System/Libary/LaunchAgents is completely locked :(
I cannot chmod, write, or chown the files.

Using Finder -> Get info, the locked checkbox is disabled for the folder and the files in it (changing owner using finder doesn't work too).

Comment: have you tried to modify the files in single user mode ?

Comment: @maetsoh Why single user mode? I would just try logging in as root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, it was the new System Integrity Protection feature in El Capitan.
I disabled that in recovery mode [using this link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3981)
:

1. Boot into recovery mode
2. Click Utilities at the top, and then Terminal
3. Type in `csrutil disable`

Answer (score 15):

El Capitan adds a new security feature named [System Integrity Protection](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) (SIP). Among other things, SIP prevents parties other than Apple from adding, deleting or modifying directories and files stored in certain directories:

```
/bin
/sbin
/usr
/System
```

Apple has indicated that the following directories are available for developers to access:

```
/usr/local
/Applications
/Library
~/Library
```

All directories in `/usr` except for `/usr/local` are protected by SIP.

Comment: Ugh. How annoying. Apples penchant for locking everything down is really starting to get old.

Comment: @tjt263 It's intended to save normal users from themselves. SIP can be turned off if you're willing to accept the lowered security.

Comment: If you're just making a quick fix like this, all you need is to either boot another OS that doesn't use SIP (ie Yosemite or any non Apple OS), or disable in recovery, do your thing, then enable again. Edits do persist even when turned back on.